# why resolution lower than accuracy

Tags: sensor, accuracy, resolution

Regards,

I've seen a few sensors which its datasheet claims to have a better resolution than the mean accuracy. 
I understand resolution as the lower identifiable value of the measurement; and, as so, half of it is the lower movement that you can see.

For example, the ds18b20 1-wire temperature sensor:

its 12bits AD resolution are analog to a 0.0625V value, and the typical error is given by:

[image: ds18b20 typical error curve]

so, suppose that I need to monitor a liquid that is between 30 and 70ºC; that fantastic resolution a third than the mean error for that gap.

I tend to think that I could extrapolate the mean curve and, in function of the current point, adjust the resolution.

But, in other example, this is the specification values for the BME280 (t/p/h) temperature sensor:

[image: bme280 temperature characteristics]

In this case I have a 0.01ºC resolution with a 0.5ºC accuracy (at best); but no error distribution chart.

So.. What it is for!??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A watch has a resolution of 1 second, but it may be 1 hour slow.

Comment: What does note 9 say? We can't see it because you forgot to link to the datasheet you're referring to.

Comment: @Chu That's actually representative of the difference between accuracy and precision more than accuracy and resolution.

Comment: I don't think you can truly extrapolate the mean error for a set of samples the way it seems you're describing it (it's actually hard to interpret what you mean), but you can calibrate your sensor with a more precise sensor. If you *know* the temperature of a sample, and you measure it with a new sensor, you can make an error correction map. That said, there's no guarantee the correction map is repeatable, which is why the error bound exists. Theoretically, you can't know the value any more accurately without additional information.

Comment: @Hari Ganti, does 'accuracy' have a quantitative definition these days?

Comment: @Chu It certainly depends on who you ask, but in the research/industry communities I've worked in, it's generally taken as the absolute minimum error bound for a single measurement. I *have* seen it used in conjunction with precision, where accuracy is labeled with averaged error bounds, combining both accuracy and precision into one convenient number.

Comment: The reason I prefer them separate is that errors in precision can be easily rectified. If you are *consistently* underestimating by 5%, you can correct by simply adding that 5% back in. However, accuracy errors tend to be more fundamental, regarding design or physical limitations rather than experimental limitations.

Comment: I guess a ticking second hand would be resolution?

Comment: Correct (while a second hand that constantly moves provides half-second resolution). Accuracy would then be its difference from UTC and precision would be characterized by whether the interval of one second is the same.

Comment: Lets say I have digital watch, which shows HH:MM:SS - then resolution is 1s (cannot show better for display len), precision can be a lot better (for really good atomic watch), or really bad (if it add noice 0-30 sec random) and both are somehow unrelated  to accuracy if it is already half an hour local time. But if I set the time right I will have still  really bad precision (because of noise - it can even go backwards ocassionally), but really good accuracy (the time follows UTC  for years with the difference just 30 seconds max at any time)

Comment: @AndrewMorton 
note 9: Temperature measured by the internal temperature sensor. This temperature value depends
on the PCB temperature, sensor element self-heating and ambient temperature and is typically
above ambient temperature. 

more, imprecise information about the error behaviour

Comment: @HariGanti ; yes but you can do that, as you said, in sistematic cases. for example the constant deviation of a voltimeter when trying to read the drop of a load of similar impedance. but, I dont think that this is the case. If it was, I could correct the meassurement with a temperature patron and srink the accuracy to the resolution

Comment: Several things to keep in mind: 1) Accuracy (when stated *alone*) typically refers to the single-measurement accuracy. That is, it answers the question, "What is the minimum deviation from the 'true' value that any single measurement can attain?" Precision refers to the spread of multiple measurements. The question it answers is, "Within what range will a series of identical measurements occupy?" Resolution answers a very different, more fundamental question, "What is the minimum fluctuation in the measured quantity that produces a response in the observed value?"

Comment: @gilhad You have essentially rephrased my prior comment with another example.

Comment: @SteAk Generally, systemic error is corrected for, yes. Rather, I've never seen a device where it wasn't corrected by the manufacturer. Shrinking the accuracy to the resolution is possible if sources of error can be eliminated or mitigated. One way this is commonly done is with redundant sensor arrays. If the error distribution is Gaussian, the mean-value theorem says we can reduce the uncertainty in our measurement with multiple samples.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, resolution and accuracy refer to two separate phenomena when taking samples:

**Accuracy**

This one is easier to understand. If the actual value of some measurable quantity is 5, then the accuracy of the measuring tool is based on how close to 5 is gets. If the tool is specified with a ±10% accuracy bound, then we could have a measurement anywhere from 4.5 to 5.5. If it is specified with a ±.10 error bound, then we could get a measurement of 4.9 to 5.1. In any case, the accuracy relates to a tool's ability to ascertain the correct value for a measurement.

**Resolution**

For analog equipment, the resolution is easy to understand. As you said, it's generally taken as half the smallest readable value. On digital electronics, however, things can get more interesting (and even on analog ones, given the next few examples). Let's say that you have a piece of silicon that produces a voltage in response to incident light (a photocell or, perhaps, a CCD). The resolution is 1V per 1W/m^2, or for an irradiance of 1W/m^2, the cell produces 1V.

As we know from photography, the ISO value is typically representative of the resolution. Increasing the ISO gets us closer to the minimum resolution, while lower ISO values allow us to set an artificial threshold higher than the minimum.

In this example, we know that photocells and CCDs respond to more than light; they also respond to heat and random quantum fluctuations. As a result, we may have a device capable of producing large voltages in response to tiny fluctuations, but because of noise inherent to the sensor design, we can't distinguish between samples within that noise band.

You can even see this with analog sensors. Sometimes, the sensor is so sensitive (some pressure gauges, as an example) that they fluctuate with system vibrations.

**Combining the Two**

Going back to the light sensor, if the baseline noise value is ±5V, then we couldn't discern differences in light for ±5W/m^2 because they *could* all have the same reading (within the same ±5V range). Thus, the accuracy of such a device is now ±5V/(W/m^2) while the resolution is still 1V/(W/m^2).

Ultimately, the resolution simply tells you the sensitivity of a measuring tool while the accuracy tells you the threshold for identifying unique samples.

**Bonus Section: Precision**

If you're really lucky, you'll get a datasheet including long-term performance, to show drift characteristics, or error bounds for multiple samples of the same quantity, to show you absolute precision. Just because a sensor *can* read to the ppm (parts per million), and just because it *is* accurate (*for a single measurement*) to the ppt (parts per thousand), that doesn't mean you can ever get meaningful data if the precision is limited to the ppp (parts per part).

Comment: The official terminology to use is "uncertainty of measurement" or UOM and that will take you into the statistics.

Comment: It depends very much on the field you're in. As I pointed out, my fields have typically considered all three measurements separately. It provides the most information, allowing for the best data analysis. When I've heard "uncertainty," it has always been in the context of Gaussian fits to datasets, in which the mean-value theorem then applies.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I understand the concepts. But i cannot help remember my electric measurements assignature teacher hiting us with a stick if we express the value of a meassurement with more digits than the accuracy.
As you said, without 'lucky' complete and detailed datasheets, I dont see the utility of such resolutions.

Comment: I actually explained something like this to a friend of mine who is a teacher since he wondered the same thing. *It all depends on the field.* Practically, digits beyond our certainty are useless, but they provide insight into the processes. If our resolution far exceeds the accuracy, it can tell us that the measurement techniques may have contributed to (or done little to mitigate) errors. It can also tell us how things like thermal noise conflate with photocell activity or other correlational data.

Comment: Collecting data is often quite easy. The real challenge is in data analysis and statistics.